# How do you put signs on the ground in a raid?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Here is what I am talking about:

[image: Screenshot of signs]

When I am tanking for my guild, I always have to ask someone to do it, because it does not work for me from the slide-in from the standard raid interface. Guild told me it works via the slide in, but it does not work for me. I am always Raid Leader or Assistant so I should have the rights to do that.

How exactly do I put those signs down? It would be really handy for my future tanking endeavours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are world marks (or also "raid beacons"). You have to be promoted in order to place them while member of a raid.
You can find the option to set them when expanding the raid-control (per default on the left side of the screen)

[image: screenshot of controls]

It is also possible to place them with a macro/console command:

> /worldmarker 1
>
> /clearworldmarker 1

'1' is an example here, you can use 1-8 for the different symbols. The beacon should occur at your mousecursorposition then.

Further information and a howto for macros can be found [here](http://wow.gamepedia.com/Raid_Beacon)